# Find Self location of a Jar file

Tags: java, path, jar

Is there any way by which we can find the current location from where the jar is forked, programmatically? Say I am executing a Jar from `D:/Jars/myjar.jar`, so can I get that path from the code?

---

@AljoshaBre I tried this

```
try {
        File file = new File(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (Exception e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Is throwing NPE. :(

But

```
System.out.println(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
```

is showing client.jar only. Not the absolute path. It is inside a Jar.

Comment: Maybe it's throwing NPE because your code is **not** yet packaged into a JAR file during unit testing?

Comment: Thanks @yegor256 but I am not uni testing. I am executing the jar itself.

Comment: You need split the sequence of calls (`getClass().getProtectionDomain().`..) in multiple lines in order to know what exactly returned `null` instead of expected instance.

Comment: @TapasBose how you solved NPE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a way:

```
return new File(ClassA.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().g‌​etPath());
```

Comment: Thanks I have added a code. But it is throwing NullPointerException

Comment: @TapasBose in what case you got NPE can you elaborate and how you solved it?

Answer (score -4):

If you execute it as `java -jar D:/Jars/myjar.jar` if you do

```
new File("afile").getAbsolutePath();
```

it will return *D:/Jars/afile* and the you can just do a substring.

The new File create the file from the folder which the jar is, so if you import this JAR in an application this method doesn't work.

Sorry I've just tried...it isn't true :P it return the path of where you called the 'java' command

Comment: Thanks, If I execute from cmd `java -jar "C:\Users\Tanmoy\Desktop\Movie Library.jar"` then `System.out.println(new File("afile").getAbsolutePath());` prints `C:\Users\Tanmoy\afile` but without `Desktop` how can I substring?